# MySQL Workbench: Orphaned document changes detected

Tags: mysql

Each time I open MySQL Workbench, I get this annoying message at the bottom of the screen saying "Orphaned document changes detected". It comes up whether I close all the SQL Editor workspaces or not. Dismissing the error doesn't help either. I did a Google search of the exact error message but it only yields four results.

Anyone here who has faced the same issue in the past? How do I clean up these "orphaned documents" or completely disable this message?

FYI:
I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate x64 and the only customization that's made to MySQL Workbench is that I've disabled the query results limit.

Comment: Also tried upgrading my Workbench, but that didn't help either. I'm using version 5.2.38

Comment: I think this question should be moved to Superuser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my case, the problem was caused by deleting the connection with orphaned document changes.

The solution for OpenSuse Linux:

- Locate ~/.mysql/workbench/sql_workspaces/*your connection name*.autosave directory
- Delete it.

As simple as that.

On Windows, the above directory should be located somewhere in AppData.

Comment: Yup, your answer knocked the problem out. Thanks! For Windows users, the sql_workspaces directory is in: C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\ (just in case anyone stumbles into this issue). I deleted whatever directory was within that.

Answer (score 2):

On Mac OS X the location is:

```
~/Library/Application Support/MySQL/Workbench/sql_workspaces
```

delete all the files therein, open mysqlworkbench

Answer (score 0):

> Stop MySQL Workbench and run the Windows Explorer. Change to the directory of the Workbench application data, for example:

C: \ Users \  AppData \ Roaming \ MySQL \ Workbench \ sql_workspaces \

Delete the contents of this directory to fix the problem. For security reasons you may first make a copy of the data.

Comment: No need to duplicate post answers, especially those from many months ago.